# How can I php validate my form data so that it has to include content?

Tags: php, html, validation

so I have created a html form that gives the information to the document that holds the html form, and I want a php check to make sure that a particular field has information in it, my code looks like this.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $errors = array();
    if ( ! isset($_POST['dbname'])) {
        array_push($errors,'dbname');
    }
        if ( ! isset($_POST['dbpass'])) {
        array_push($errors, 'dbpass');
        }
            if ( ! isset($_POST['dbhost'])) {
        array_push($errors, 'dbhost');
        }
            if ( ! isset($_POST['prefix'])) {
        array_push($errors, 'prefix');
        }
            if (isset($_POST['dbname']) && trim($_POST['dbname']) != '' {
            echo "something";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "nothing";
            }

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        $error_msg = implode('<br>', $errors);
        show_form($error_msg);
    }
    else {
        do_install();
        echo 'Install Done';
    }
}
else {
    // show the form
    show_form();
}
```

The line that is giving me trouble is

```
if (isset($_POST['dbname']) && trim($_POST['dbname']) != ''
```

basically I thought this line would essentially say "if the field dbname is set and its value when trimming it is equal to something then do this, if not then do this" but instead when I added this line in the whole thing just broke and stopped displaying anything in the browser.

incase you need it the rest of my file looks like this

```
function show_form($msg = '') {
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php if (isset($msg) && trim($msg) != '') { echo $msg; } ?>
        <P> HI </P>
        <form action="hi.php" method="POST">
            <p>Your Database name and user: <input type="text" name="dbname" /><br />
            Your database password <input type="text" name="dbpass" /> <br/>
            Your DB_HOST (ip address) <input type ="text" name = "dbhost" /> <br/> 
            Your desired table prefix <input type ="text" name = "prefix" /> <br />
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></p>
        </form>
<?php
        }
        ?>
<?php
function recurseRmdir($di) {
  $files = array_diff(scandir($di), array('.','..'));
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    (is_dir("$di/$file")) ? recurseRmdir("$di/$file") : unlink("$di/$file");
  }
  return rmdir($di);
}
?>
<?php
function do_install() { 
    chdir(__DIR__);
    $dir = getcwd(); /** stores the directory that the php file is in as a variable */
    file_put_contents($dir . '/wordpress.zip', file_get_contents('http://wordpress.org/latest.zip'));
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open('wordpress.zip');
    $zip->extractTo($dir);
    $zip->close();
    unlink($dir . '/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/hello.php');
    recurseRmdir($dir . '/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/akismet');
    recurseRmdir($dir . '/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen');
    recurseRmdir($dir . '/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen');
    recurseRmdir($dir . '/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve');
    file_put_contents ($dir . '/wpbfboilerplate.zip', file_get_contents ('/home/wpbfboilerplate.zip'));
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open('wpbfboilerplate.zip');
    $zip->extractTo($dir);
    $zip->close();
    unlink($dir . '/wordpress.zip');
    unlink($dir . '/wpbfboilerplate.zip');
    rename($dir . '/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php', $dir . '/wordpress/wp-config.php');
    $contents = file_get_contents($dir . '/wordpress/wp-config.php');
    $new_contents = str_replace('database_name_here',$dbname, $contents);
    file_put_contents('wordpress/wp-config.php', $new_contents);
    $contents = file_get_contents($dir . '/wordpress/wp-config.php');
    $new_contents = str_replace('username_here', $dbname, $contents);
    file_put_contents('wordpress/wp-config.php', $new_contents);
    $contents = file_get_contents($dir . '/wordpress/wp-config.php');
    $new_contents = str_replace('localhost', $dbhost, $contents);
    file_put_contents('wordpress/wp-config.php', $new_contents);
    $contents = file_get_contents($dir . '/wordpress/wp-config.php');
    $new_contents = str_replace('password_here', $dbpass, $contents);
    file_put_contents('wordpress/wp-config.php', $new_contents);
    $contents = file_get_contents($dir . '/wordpress/wp-config.php');
    $new_contents = str_replace("\$table_prefix  = 'wp_';", "\$table_prefix  =" . "'" . $prefix . "'", $contents);
    file_put_contents('wordpress/wp-config.php', $new_contents);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['dbname']) && trim($_POST['dbname']) != '')`
should work. The cause of the error must be something else.

Comment: Hahaha solved it, simple stupid early morning error!

Comment: Should have been
if (isset($_POST['dbname']) && trim($_POST['dbname']) != '') {
I simply forgot the bracket! xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have been if (isset($_POST['dbname']) && trim($_POST['dbname']) != '') { I simply forgot the bracket! xD

Comment: Turn error reporting on, it will save you a lot of time. (Notifications and warnings can be off)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if(!$_POST['dbname']){
    $data['Error']='Please enter DB Name.';
    show_form($data['Error']); // show the form
}elseif(!$_POST['dbpass']){
    $data['Error']='Please enter DB password.';
    show_form($data['Error']); // show the form
}elseif(!$_POST['dbhost']){
    $data['Error']='Please enter DB Host.';
    show_form($data['Error']); // show the form
}elseif(!$_POST['prefix']){
    $data['Error']='Please enter DB Prefix.';
    show_form($data['Error']); // show the form
}else{
        do_install();
        echo 'Install Done';
}
```

Do somthing like this, I hope above will help.

Comment: I have already solved it and anyway the above would not help, your code only checks if the field data has been posted, but because in PHP no content still is identified as being posted, it would not verify that a user has put data in. Thank you anyway :)